# Facebook page: How to add a customized box at the bottom left side of wall tab?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

Dear all, I have a question about Facebook Page: (*NOT* user profile page, I mean a facebook page where you can become a fan)

How to add a customized box at the bottom left side of wall tab? 
(I am the page creator/admin)

Please don't just give an answer "add the box to the page". Cause I really don't know how.

Also, it seems that putting $facebook->api_client->profile_setFBML and $facebook->api_client->profile_setInfo for the application won't provide a way for the page to add the box.

Below is an example image that is done by the other. I have circled the box at the image. I would like to know how to do the same to the page that I owned. Many thanks for reading.

[alt text http://design.outblaze.com/calvin/facebook/facebookPageBoxQ.jpg](http://design.outblaze.com/calvin/facebook/facebookPageBoxQ.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $facebook->api_client->profile_setFBML
```

is absolutely correct afair.  Go to the App Page and Add the App to your Fan Page. It will most properbly appear in the Boxes Tab.

```
    // get the fbml for the box 
    $main_box = $this->render();
    // the first main_box is actually deprecated feel free not to use it
    $this->facebook->api_client->profile_setFBML($main_box, PAGE_ID, $main_box, NULL, $main_box, $main_box);
    // for easier workflow forward the user directly to the page
    $this->facebook->redirect(PAGE_URL);
```

But as said by others in this thread in 90% of the cases the [Static FBML](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=4949752878&ref=s) App by Facebook does the job.

Answer (score 2):

Unreality's answer helped me best but one clarification is needed. These boxes can be added only to "Pages" that you have admin rights to.  You cannot add one of these boxes to your profile page from what I can see.  (Anybody? Prove me wrong, please!)

Answer (score 1):

You write an application that has a box. You add the box to the page, then move the box to the page's wall.

For example, I moved the Notes box on my app's page to my wall so you could see it:

http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=96193636102

**Update, with more info:**

In general, the way you do this is you add a function to your app that creates a block of fbml and passes it to setFBML(), using your page's ID instead of a user ID as the destination.

I'm planning to do this myself to add some summary statistics to my app's profile page, but that has to wait til after working hours.

Comment: >"You add the box to the page"  But.how.to.add.the.box.to.the.page?thx. ;p

Comment: > But.how.to.add.the.box.to.the.page

You.write.an.application. See http://developer.facebook.com.

Comment: I know you can do it with coding way, I know about setFBML. I have finished writing the application. What I want to know is to find the button which add the box to the page.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer. It's using the static fbml made from facebook

http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=4949752878&ref=s

Go there, click "add to my page", and pick your page.

Then goto your own page, and click "Edit page", then you will find FBML under the applications.

Click the pencil at the FBML box top right, select edit.

Then at the edit page, just write something up and save the changes

Next go back to your own page. Goto the "Boxes" tab, you will find the FBML box that you have just made.

Click the pencil button at the FBML box, select "Move to Wall Tab", and then done! Happy FaceBooking!

Comment: So, instead of writing an app to add the FBML to your page, you found someone else's app that does it for you.

I... guess that's okay, if all you want to do is put a static un-changing box on your page's profile.

Comment: Actually, I have to ask a question - if you weren't planning on writing your own app, why did you ask this question on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Um this is not "someone else's app", this is the official facebook app. I do look for the coding answer too, but this static fbml app done the work. The setFBML function only set the box content, it won't add the box to the page. I would like to know where can I push the button to make the content in setFBML appear in the page. I can't find the button to do that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the profile boxes will be removed soon.